# Excel formula compare current and history data

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to compare current and history data to find out if number field is matching.
Currently, there are columns A through AM. However, the combination of S, T, U columns makes a unique row.
So I want to compare that combination to sheet2(history data) to find out if column Z is matching to the current value, and return "pass" if matching to the history data, and "review" if is not matching to history data. Is there any way to write this formula in Excel? I've tried to make a unique field by creating formula like this `s2&t2&u2` both in history and current data, but vlookup does not work on this. Is there any way to make this process work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this *array formula* at any cell of row 2 of sheet 1, then copy/paste along the column to check each of the rows.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,
  (Sheet2!$S$2:$S$1000=S2)*
  (Sheet2!$T$2:$T$1000=T2)*
  (Sheet2!$U$2:$U$1000=U2)*
  (Sheet2!$Z$2:$Z$1000=Z2),
  0)), "pass","review")         Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Remember, this is an array formula, edit it then type `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` otherwise it won't work.